# Word to express something analogous to sample?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say for example, many guys are told to harass Tom in different different ways. Now Tom wants to say that if you catch hold of any 1 guy among those concerned, the investigation team will get a "sample" of what is happening with Tom. By sample I mean the team will get an idea that people are being told to harass Tom. So what that one guy reveals will describe the whole scene or circumstances around Tom. So that revelation is what will serve as a "sample". I know that sample isn't the word that fits the context, so what word can substitute 'sample'?

Comment: Clue, hint, idea, evidence, view, angle etc. Look for synonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given the answer to your own question, by simple usage, in the explanation of your request.

Please allow me to rephrase *your answer*.

After getting an **example** of the kinds of individuals harassing Tom, you would have some **idea** of what befell Tom.